# Sound Devices recorders maximum link cable length?

Tags: 744t, 722, 702, field-recording

From the Sound Devices web site:

*Although the RS-232 standard allows for cable lengths of up to 50 feet, the recommended maximum length of C.Link cable between any given pair of 7-series recorders is 4 feet. Longer cables lengths introduce the risk of the slave unit losing word clock synchronization with the master unit.*

Has anyone had success running long link cables (between 4 and 50 feet)? Or longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The C. Link protocol links carries the following data:
• word clock 
• time code information (744T, 702T only) 
• RS-232 machine transport data"

Its probably wordclock that you'd want to be most careful with...

from Sound Devices website:
http://www.sounddevices.com/notes/recorders/linking-recorders/

Although the RS-232 standard allows for cable lengths of up to 50 feet, the recommended maximum length of C.Link cable between any given pair of 7-series recorders is 4 feet. Longer cables lengths introduce the risk of the slave unit losing word clock synchronization with the master unit.

Comment: @tim prebble I've got the same quote fron the SD site in my original post. I was just wondering if there were any alternative solutions that anyone has come up with. I've been chatting with our studio tech about this and he thinks it may be possible to build an active cable with an adapter that converts to a CAT 5 run. Trying to get him on the phone with SD to see if his idea is viable. Will update...

Comment: wish they would implement a system like Zaxcom have, using wifi for sync, machine control, metadata, timecode etc



Answer (score 1):

Aye,

Not recommended to go too far - C.Link definitely won't do ya. And as far as I know, there isn't a signal strength booster/interference guard.

BNC should work for 50 foot runs though.
I had referenced an audio-tech sales employee about this for doing gun-range recording. Also, here is an online reference:
http://www.ehow.com/decision_6867184_long-can-run-bnc-cable_.html

What are your thoughts?

---

- Curtis - c3sound.com

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would work, but you could try transmitting the signal across a radio link?